# I have some phone numbers with names in data set 2 that match some names in data set 1 without phone numbers... how can find these and condense?

Tags: google-sheets

I currently am working on creating filled out contacts in data set 1. I have around 600 names, some filled, some missing phone numbers. This set of data has several columns but the only one I'm focusing on is phone numbers. I have a second set of data that has names and phone numbers (contacts exported from a phone into a csv.). This set has around 3000 contacts. I need to find the matching names that are in set 1 and set 2, and then move the phone numbers of those matching names into set 1. The result should be set 1 now with more phone numbers filled out because I used set 2. Does anyone know how to efficently do this rather than going down the list and searching for a matching name?

Comment: What should happen if there are phone numbers in both?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a typical case for VLOOKUP. You might use the version that returns a single value, which implies using multiple formulas, one for each row, or the version that returns an array. Below is one example formula for each *version*:

Single value

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0)
```

Multiple values

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0))
```

It's worth noting that there are many ways to achieve the result you are looking for, the most common of which is using formulas. Another popular method is to use Google Apps Script.